# Add loop for each month to check available date python not only mentioned month of year

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver

[My bot not check other months only checking given month if it doesn't have available date then it picks next any available date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zghDx.png)

I want my bot to check all the 12 months till given yearly range if any date available between today to till end of the range bot should mention the date.

Here is my code

```
dd = driver.find_element(By.ID, ("ui-datepicker-div"))
    current_month = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month").text
    current_year = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year").text

    while not (current_month.__eq__("April") and current_year.__eq__("2025")):
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']").click()
        current_month = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month").text
        current_year = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year").text
        print(current_month, current_year)
    dd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay'][@data-event='click']").click()

    paragraph3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay'][@data-event='click']").get_attribute(
        "textContent")
    print(paragraph3)
    d = "{} {} {}".format(current_year, current_month,paragraph3)
    print(d)
    # Find an element by its ID
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'appointments_consulate_appointment_date')

    # Get text content of element
    text_content = element.text
    print(text_content)
    time.sleep(5)
    # Close the driver
    driver.quit()
```

In this code bot only show April 2025 dates and if April don't have any available date then bot picks may date.

I am getting confused in looping system, my bot just checking dates in given year of month not checking all months till the end of the range.